# How to use @available with class variables

Tags: swift

How would I create a specific iOS 14 class variable?

I tried these two forms with a `@available` property builder:

```
struct Blabla {
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    @Namespace private var animation
}
```

```
struct Blabla {
    @available(iOS 14.0, *) @Namespace private var animation
}
```

but it shows this error: `'Namespace' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer`.

Comment: Btw, one solution for those seeking an easy/nobrain solution is to duplicate this class and make it @available for iOS14. But i am looking for a s*xier method!

Comment: There is no availability for properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is no, we can't :(

Only at function or class level. In my case, I duplicated the class and renamed the previous one to `MyClass13`. And I put a if @available where i need to call it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually set availability [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVrQY.png)
after cou can store some static properties and shared ll inside your app

Comment: Yeah on the class level. I was just wondering if I missed something in the doc to actually put it on a variable level.